# Kotlin enum like in the swift

Tags: kotlin

I have enum in swift

```
enum Type {
    case bool(Bool)
    case int(Int)
    case array([String])
}
```

Dont understand how i can convert this to kotlin code, i did like this:

```
enum class AnswerSheetType {
    BOOL,
    INT,
    ARRAY
}
```

But how i can pass variable to enum type. For example then i want create method which will be return type with variable, like this(swift code):

```
func marks(for id: String) -> Type {
    let answer = answers?[id]
    
    if let boolAnswer = answer as? Bool {
        return .bool(boolAnswer)
    }
    if let intAnswer = answer as? Int {
        return .int(intAnswer)
    }
    if let arrayAnswer = answer as? [String] {
        return .array(arrayAnswer)
    }
}
```

Comment: enums in kotlin can't store any associated data. Sealed classes are probably the next best thing. See https://medium.com/@arturogdg/creating-enums-with-associated-data-in-kotlin-d9e2cdcf4a99 for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a sealed interface/class to represent this.

```
sealed interface Type {

    data class BoolType(val value: Bool) : Type
    data class IntType(val value: Int) : Type
    data class ArrayType(val value: Array<String>) : Type

    // if you have a case that doesn't have any associated values, just use an object
    // object CaseWithoutAssociatedValues: Type

}
```

Usage:

```
// let someType: Type = .bool(true)
val someType: Type = Type.BoolType(true)

// just like how you can use a switch on a Swift enum, you can use a when like this too:
// This when is also exhaustive, if you specify all the implementers of Type
when (someType) {
    is Type.BoolType -> println("Bool value: ${someType.value}")
    is Type.IntType -> println("Int value: ${someType.value}")
    is Type.ArrayType -> println("Array value: ${someType.value}")
}
```

Notice that in each of the branches, you can access `someType.value`, because of the smart-cast. This is unlike in Swift, where you would do pattern matching to get the associated values out.

Comment: i see, kotlin is strange for me now) Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a slightly more complicated (but perhaps more powerful) alternative, the `value` property could be a property (concrete or abstract) in the `Type` interface (parameterised with its type); then you could refer to `type` before checking for the concrete type.

Comment: Exactly what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As I was writing my answer Sweeper already answered with almost the identical solution. I wanted to add to that, that your `marks` function could then be written as this:

```
fun marks(id: String) : Type? {
    when (val answer = answers?.get(id)) {
        is Boolean -> return Type.BoolType(answer)
        is Int -> return Type.IntType(answer)
        is Array<*> -> if (answer.isArrayOf<String>()) return Type.ArrayType(answer as Array<String>)
    }
    return null
}
```

The `Array` case is a bit ugly but that is because checking on `is Array<String>` is not possible. The IDE will also still complain about having an unchecked cast but it should work. I don't know if there's a nicer way to handle this.